# How do I call this script?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a script for deleting a record without refreshing. I'm still new to javascript and trying to learn how to call out this script. Here's what I have.

My button:

```
<button id="<?php echo $rrr['id']; ?>" class="delbutton" onclick="">Delete</button>
```

My Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(function() {

        $(".delbutton").click(function() {
            var del_id = $(this).attr("id");
            var info = 'id=' + del_id;
            if (confirm("Sure you want to delete this note? This cannot be undone later.")) {
                $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url : "delete-note.php", //URL to the delete php script
                    data : info,
                    success : function() {
                    }
                });
                $(this).parents(".record").animate("fast").animate({
                    opacity : "hide"
                }, "slow");
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
```

I borrowed this code from someone else while doing research for deleting without reloading. Normally I'd see a function look something like this:

```
function myFunction()
```

Then I can call it using onclick like this:

```
onclick="myFunction()"
```

With the way this script is written, I'm not sure what "function" I'm supposed to be calling or if I need to add the name somewhere.

Any guidance or reading material would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: first of all, you should place the code to remove the record front-end in the Success callback. this way you will wait for the record to actually be deleted before hiding it.

Comment: Also, you don't need the `onclick`, there is a click listener in Jquery on your button allready.

Comment: Your JavaScript binds a function to a click event: `$(".delbutton").click(function() {`, so you don't need an `onclick` attribute on the button. What seems to go wrong? What happens when you click the button?

Comment: [.click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: @Nicolas I can see what your saying about the success call. Thanks! Also, nothing happens when I click the button with the onclick attribute or without it.

Comment: That's strange. Do you get any JavaScript errors in your browser's console?
 Can you create a working demo? Is the button inside a `<form>`? By default, I'd expect the `<button>` at least to submit your form...

Comment: You can try replace with `$('.delButton').on('click', function(){ ... })` instead, might works.

Comment: @Nicolas I will try replacing it with your suggestion. I have a life demo you could look at if you need. Let me try your suggestion real quick though.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any error in your console, ( Ctrl + shift + I ) , because your javascript code works in my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eo0eeppm/

Comment: @Nicolas I replaced my code with your suggestion above and still got nothing. I can give you the access to the demo with user/pass if you'd like.

Comment: I just double checked my console and I have zero javascript errors. I have an error telling me I'm trying to serve http connections over an https site.

Comment: Do you at least have a popup for your confirmation when you click the button ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157927/discussion-between-matthew-davis-and-nicolas).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use an `onclick` here:

`$(".delbutton")` finds all the buttons with the CSS class `delbutton`.

`.click(function() { ... })` says execute the given function when the button is clicked.

Comment: I tried removing the onlclick and refreshed the page. When the button was clicked, nothing happened.

Comment: Something you're not showing us is causing an issue - you can see from the minimal reproduction here (https://jsfiddle.net/18Lma3ay/1/) the click handler is fine.

Comment: Is there any possibility it could be where I have the script placed? I have it in the footer of my page.

Comment: Provided it is within the body it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
```

This means everything in there is being called when the document is ready.

As UncleDave already said, because of the .click your script should already be called onclick. It would be the same if you replace this line:

```
$(".delbutton").click(function() {
```

with this line:

```
function myOnClickFunction() {
```

and then call it onClick via onClick="myOnClickFunction()"

Answer (score 0):

The [`click`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) function binds the function as an event handler to the click event on all the elements matched by the [selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) passed to the [`jQuery` function which is aliased to `$`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).

(This replaces the `onclick` attribute)

To call the function, just click the matching element (any element that is a member of the `delbutton` class).

You could also trigger the event programatically with the [`trigger` method](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

```
$(".delbutton").trigger("click");
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(".delbutton").click(function()` is listening to any click to trigger the action which is the code in your function.

You don't need `onclick=""` for the `button` tag.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I call this script?

You already do, it is self executing.

You do not need to register a sepperate click event to the button. The script is doing this already itself.

```
$(".delbutton").click(function() {
// code being executed when button is pressed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it the way you are used to, just create your function in the  tag like this:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  // do something
}
</script>
```

then, your HTML  element should look like this:

`<button onclick="myFunction()" >`